# Search distinct date parts fast in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I've got a database of ~10 million entries, each of which contains a date stored as [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

I've indexed that column using a non-unique BTREE.

I'm running a query that counts the number of entries for each distinct year:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(awesome_date)) as year, COUNT(id) as count
FROM all_entries
WHERE awesome_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(awesome_date)
ORDER BY year DESC;
```

The query takes about 90 seconds to run at the moment, and the EXPLAIN output demonstrates why:

```
id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows     | Extra
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | all_entries  | ALL   | awesome_date  |     |         |     | 9759848  |  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

If I `FORCE KEY(awesome_date)` that drops the rows count down to ~8 million and the `key_len = 4`, but is still `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`.

I also run queries selecting `DISTINCT(MONTH(awesome_date))` and `DISTINCT(DAY(awesome_date))` with the relevant `WHERE` conditions restricting them to a particular year or month.

Other than storing the year, month and day information in separate columns, is there a way of speeding up this query and/or avoiding temporary tables and filesort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without splitting the date to 3 columns, you could:

- First, you should remove the DISTINCT, it is useless. – ypercube 1 min ago edit
- Remove the `ORDER BY year`, it would help improve speed (a bit). Change the `Group By` to: `GROUP BY YEAR(awesome_date) DESC` (this works in MySQL dialect only).
- Change the `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(*)` (assuming that `id` can never be `NULL`, this is faster in many MySQL versions).

In all, the query will become:

```
SELECT YEAR(awesome_date) AS year
     , COUNT(*) AS cnt              --- not good practise to use reserved words
                                    --- for aliases
FROM all_entries
WHERE awesome_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(awesome_date) DESC ;
```

---

Even better (faster) solutions are:

- your proposal to split the column into 3 (year, month, day)
- change from MySQL to MariaDB (that is a MySQL fork) and use [`VIRTUAL PERISTENT`](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/virtual-columns) column for the year, and add an index on that virtual column.
- stay in MySQL and add a persistent `year` column yourself - by using triggers.